# Reflection and annotation that doesn't define

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have programmed an app that gets name of an entity class and based on it, makes a UI.
For doing so I created a few annotations and used them for the entity fields. One of these annotations is `@Label` that holds the name field and others are `@IntType`, `@StringType`,... that hold the field types.

I want to know, if I write an entity for creating a UI that doesn't have one or both of the annotations, how do I handle these exception? Just with a try/catch block?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom exception like **AnotationNotFoundException**, and throw it where you control the anotations of entity. Then catch it in your main method of app. You can log it somewhere like ui or log files.

Comment: if customer doesn't implement AnotationNotFoundException , then what shall I do? is there any way that make customer to implement a custom annotation? like @override?

Comment: @poursina when your code is run and it looks for these annotations it can throw an exception.  You can't make the program do something without running any code.